# Ubuntu 1304 Mount NAS Synology

Tags: mount

I do have a question concerning mount of NAS via a network from outside.
Unfortunately I have no clue how I can mount a NAS from a extern network. 
I did a VPN setup between 2 routers, so far I was able to get it work, but now I'm in doubt how I can handle the mount to my NAS from outside via Internet.

I hope somebody do have a hint for me?

regards
Alf

Answer (score 0):

Just went through exact same problem. Synology site explains how to do this on some ancient ubuntu, but on current version with unity "places->connect server" doesn't exist.

Anyway, just now I managed to get access using [this](http://deathofagremmie.com/2012/05/01/mounting-a-synology-diskstation-on-ubuntu-12.04/#disqus_thread) in 5min. It kinda assumes you know how to use basic command line and file editing. If you have problems ask.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.